# How do I match versions of Wildfly 9.0.1 w/ org.wildfly.arquillian:wildfly-arquillian-container-managed?

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, jboss-arquillian, wildfly-9

Upgrading a J2EE application from Wildfly 8.2.1.FInal to 9.0.1.Final I
discovered the namespace and versioning change of the Arquillian
Wildfly container.

In the JBoss Developer forum I read

> This is working with the Maven "org.wildfly.arquillian" group
>   artifacts instead, having versions matching the Wildfly J2EE spec
>   instead of the Wildfly container version, seems more reasonable
>   both by name and version numbering.

What is the "Wildfly J2EE spec" and how do I go about matching Wildfly
versions with versions of
`org.wildfly.arquillian:wildfly-arquillian-container-managed`?

Cheers
Mats

**Addendum**

If someone lands in this page because they have that same problem here is my recommendation: [Arquillian Chameleon for the sake of simplicity](http://www.lordofthejars.com/2016/09/arquillian-chameleon-for-sake-of.html). Arquillian Chameleon is an automatic container downloader-install-container manager for Arquillian integration tests.

If you're going for the `org.wildfly.arquillian:wildfly-arquillian-container-managed`, the verion to use with Wildfly 9.0.1.Final is `org.wildfly.arquillian:wildfly-arquillian-container-managed:1.0.0.Final`.

Comment: I found out that the Wildfly 9.0.1.Final is best matched with the `org.wildfly.arquillian:wildfly-arquillian-container-managed:1.0.0.Final` and I also came across the Arquillian Chameleon which seems great. I still wonder what "the Wildfly J2EE spec" stands for and how to decide it for future versions of Wildfly.

Comment: This poster was complaining about the lack of a versioning relationship between wildfly-arquillian-* versions and WildFly versions. "Wildfly J2EE spec" is a nonsense term in the context of the posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way to work out what version of Arquillian jars to use with a specific version of WildFly is to look at the [WildFly Source](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly) on GitHub.

Click on the "Branch: master" button and choose the "Tags" tab.

Look down the list until you find 9.0.1.Final and select it.

Open the [pom.xml](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/9.0.1.Final/pom.xml) file and search the page for `version.org.wildfly.arquillian`.

You will see

```
 <version.org.wildfly.arquillian>1.0.0.Final</version.org.wildfly.arquillian>
```

which is the version that you're after.

For 10.1.0.Final it says:

```
 <version.org.wildfly.arquillian>1.0.2.Final</version.org.wildfly.arquillian>
```

which looks like a bug fix release that will likely work just fine with WildFly 9.0.1 as well.

Comment: Wow. Great answer. Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of dealing with versions of container adapters is to use Arquillian Chameleon - it will take care of all the dependencies hurdles for you. The only thing you need to specify is a target container as a property, e.g. `wildfly:9.1.0.Final:managed`.

For more details have a look in the official repository: https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-container-chameleon#arquillian-chameleon-container-

Comment: :) I found that as well and I'm actually going with that in the long run, although I'm trying the `org.wildfly.arquillian:wildfly-arquillian-container-managed` 1.0.0.Final as well as 1.0.2.Final. Setting up Chameleon was so easy I couldn't believe it :)